# How to pass a secrets manager value in HTTP header of an api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-secrets-manager

I have a token saved in Secrets Manager and I need to set it in the Authorization var HTTP header. Is this possible?

I tried to retrieve it using a lambda but not find a way to call my lambda to set it or call it from Secrets Manager directly.

[HTTP Header env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78RhE.png)

I only found examples calling the lambda function that receives the value of the header, but not the returns to it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to retrieve a value from secrets manager without making aws api call, so potentially you will have to have a chain of Lambda functions, perhaps all of them will be http invoked. One Lambda makes a call to one api gw endpoint, invoking another Lambda that copies headers received, adds value from Secrets Manager and calling next Lambda in a chain, also thru API GW. However, this seems to be a bad design. My suggestion is to use custom Lambda authorizer (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html) where you authorise your api call and this authorizer func can go to secrets manager, obtain value from it and add to the header. My suggestion is to use either node.js or golang for writing this authorizer lambdas, due to speed requirements. Think about caching of this authoriser response - also for speed!